# Notificationintent assigns data of last index for all notifications

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
    private void pushlocalnotificationsoffers(String noTitle, String notText, int p) {
    notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_rush_for_less)
            .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromURL(shopsInfos.get(p).getIcon()))
            .setContentTitle(noTitle)
            .setContentText(notText);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putString("shopid", shopsInfos.get(p).getId());
    editor.apply();
    for (int z=0;z<producstInfos.size();z++) {

        int requestcode=0;
        notificationIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, Display_Clicked_Offer_Info.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("IDITEM", producstInfos.get(z).getId());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("CATID", producstInfos.get(z).getCat_id());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("shopname", producstInfos.get(z).getShopname());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("itemname", producstInfos.get(z).getProductname());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("oldPrice", producstInfos.get(z).getPrice());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("newPrice", producstInfos.get(z).getOffers());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("itemsavailableofproducts", producstInfos.get(z).getQuantity());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("imageBigProduct", producstInfos.get(z).getUrlimage());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("shopIcon", producstInfos.get(z).getUrl_shop_icon());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("details", producstInfos.get(z).getDetails());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("shopid", producstInfos.get(z).getShop_iD());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("starttime", producstInfos.get(z).getStarting_time());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("endtime", producstInfos.get(z).getEnding_time());
        Log.e("notiINFO", "product at index [" + z + "] id item " + producstInfos.get(z).getId() + " cat id" + producstInfos.get(z).getCat_id() + " shop name " + producstInfos.get(z).getShopname() + " item name "
                + producstInfos.get(z).getProductname() + " old price" + producstInfos.get(z).getPrice() + " new price" + producstInfos.get(z).getOffers() + " items available " + producstInfos.get(z).getQuantity() +
                " img prod " + producstInfos.get(z).getUrlimage() + " shop icon " + producstInfos.get(z).getUrl_shop_icon() + " details" + producstInfos.get(z).getDetails() +
                " shop id" + producstInfos.get(z).getShop_iD() + " start time" + producstInfos.get(z).getStarting_time() + " end time" + producstInfos.get(z).getEnding_time());
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), z, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    }

    currentNotificationID++;
        notificationId = currentNotificationID;
        if (notificationId == Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
            notificationId = 0;
        Log.e("NotificationsID===",""+notificationId);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) (getApplicationContext()).getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

}
```

Every notification has different assigned data, but i receive the data of last index in array for all notifications.
And Nothing is wrong with the assigned data, and i can see different data in log

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same issue.